# Angular 2/4 Protractor Debugging e2e Tests

Tags: angular, debugging, protractor

I have been searching the internet for hours trying to find a way of being able to debug some e2e tests that I have written on protractor for my Angular 2 recipe app (the tests exist in a spec file - login.e2e-spec.ts).

I want to be able to put break points in my code and step through each line of code in my spec files.

I have node 8.x.x installed on my machine therefore I can no longer using the browser.pause function.

Does anybody know how to successfully debug protractor spec files by stepping through each line at a time using break points?

Below is my test spec code:-

```
import { LoginPage } from './login.po';
import { CommonPage } from '../common/common.po';
import { Navigation } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { browser } from 'protractor';

describe('angular-two-recipe-app App Login', () => {
  let loginPage: LoginPage;
  let commonPage: CommonPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    commonPage = new CommonPage();
  });

  it('should successfully display the login page', async () => {
    //debugger;
    loginPage.navigateTo();
    browser.debugger();
    browser.manage().window().setSize(1680, 1050);
    expect(loginPage.getUsernameInputBox()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(loginPage.getPasswordInputBox()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(loginPage.getSubmitButton()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(loginPage.getUsernameInputBoxValue()).toBe('');
    expect(loginPage.getPasswordInputBoxValue()).toBe('');
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The protractor API has a debugger method you can use. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.debugger

For example:

```
it('clicks a link', async () => {
    await element(by.css('#link')).click();
    browser.debugger();
    // ...some other action
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the information. I tried doing the above but the tests just ran straight through i.e. the code does not stop when it reaches the 'browser.debugger()' section

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the test?

Comment: Hi again. Yes, Ill add it above in my question. Thanks for you help :-)

Comment: It could be due to the ordering. Try putting the debugger line below the line where you set the screen size. You'll also probably want to add some 'awaits' in your test code. await loginPage.navigateTo() await browser.debugger()

Comment: I will give that a try. I am running my tests by type the following:- ng e2e. Is that correct?

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but my tests just ran straight through again i.e. the code never stopped when it hit the await browser.debugger(); line

Comment: I usually use the protractor cli. I run 'protractor conf.js' to launch the tests where conf.js has the setup/teardown steps. Checkout the "Run the test" section on the protractor homepage. https://www.protractortest.org/#/

Comment: thanks for your post. That page u mentioned doesnt tell you where to place the 'conf.js' file though. Any ideas?

Comment: I created a conf.js file in my route. I ran - protractor conf.js, and now Im getting the following error:-

Comment: (node:7012) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[22:17:00] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[22:17:00] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[22:17:06] E/launcher - Error: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\angular-two-recipe-app\angular-two-recipe-app\e2e\login\login
.e2e-spec.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { LoginPage } from './login.po';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:93:5
[22:39:37] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100